# Difference between **(x+i) and *(*x+i)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm using an array of pointers where each index holds a pointer that points to an array of integers. While I was able to figure out how to print the values in an array using the pointer array, there is one line of code that I need clarity on. I want to understand the difference between **(x+i) and *(*x+i) as the former throws a Segmentation fault exception while the latter prints the desired output. Please refer to my example code below.

```
int pointer_array=malloc(1*sizeof(int*));
int number_array = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
*(pointer_array)=number_array; 
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
  *(pointer_array+i)=i;
}
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
  //printf("\n%d",**(pointer_arr+i));  This throws Segmentation Fault exception
    printf("\n%d",*(*pointer_arr+i)); // This prints the desired output 0 \n 1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the expressions becomes very clear if we convert them to array notation by making use of the `*(a + i) == a[i]` equivalence and its corollary `*a == a[0]`.

`**(x + i)` is `x[i][0]`, whereas `*(*x + i)` is `x[0][i]`.

In your code we want this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **pointer_array = malloc(1*sizeof(int*));
    ^^

int *number_array = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    ^
```

Then the rest of the code means this:

```
*(pointer_array)=number_array; // pointer_array[0] = number_array
```

Oops: the loop assigns integers to pointers:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
  *(pointer_array+i)=i;  // pointer_array[i] = i
}
```

The above is probably intended to be `number_array[i] = i`.

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {

  printf("\n%d",*(*pointer_arr+i)); // printf ... pointer_arr[0][i]
}
```

If we correct the first loop to initialize `number_array`, then this second loop should retrieve those values.

Otherwise we are marching over uninitialized values.

Comment: Is it better to use int** pointer_array =  malloc(1 * sizeof(void*)) for the array of pointers? Or is it that going to be the same as int*?

Comment: @neutrino_logic Neither. It's best to use the following idiom: `whatever *ptr = malloc(sizeof *whatever);` for one item or `malloc(sizeof *whatever * nelem);` for an array off `nelem` elements.

Answer (score 0):

`**(x+i)` means "evaluate `x+i`, which will give a pointer, then read the value that it points to, which will give another pointer, then read the value that it points to", or equivalently, `x[i][0]`. `*(*x+i)` means "evaluate `x`, which will give a pointer, then read the value that it points to, which will give another pointer, then add `i` to that, then read the value that it points to", or equivalently, `x[0][i]`. Obviously, these are very different expressions.

Comment: Thanks I thought as much, however there is still one thing that confuses me. Given that **(x+i) evaluates to x[i][0], when i=0 it should evaluate to x[0][0], right? So shouldn't it ideally print x[0][0] and then throw a Segmentation Fault error when it hits x[1][0](when i=1)?

Comment: @SC `printf` buffers its output. It's likely that the first print went into the buffer, and then the crash happened before the buffer was flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unsafe; `malloc` will return a `void *` — a pointer type. You are storing the results in an `int`. An `int` is not guaranteed to be large enough to store a `void *` and indeed won't be on x86, the current predominant architecture.

That being said:

- `(x+i)` if x is a pointer will evaluate to `i*sizeof(*x) + x`. So it'll evaluate to a pointer that is i slots after x;
- `**(x+i)` will therefore read the pointer from i slots after x and then read whatever that pointer points to.

So from an array of pointers to arrays, it will read the first item from the `i`th array.

Whereas:

- `*x+i` will read a pointer from `x` and then add i*sizeof(**x) to it;
- `*(*x+i)` will read a pointer from there and dereference it.

So from an array of pointers to arrays, it will read the `i`ith item from the first array.